# Java Object Oriented Question - 2

Tags: java, object-oriented-design

This is yet another follow up question about Object oriented design in general. I am trying to break them down to separate questions per advice I got from @Jay earlier.

I get a new question, almost every step of the OO design process. I tried to get the ideas from books, articles and the web. It just gets more muddied up. I would like to get some advice from the experts here, so I can get my concepts right.

Say I have the below Objects:

```
public class AddressRecord {
  protected String addressLine1;
  protected String addressLine2;
  protected String city;
  protected String state;
  protected String postalCode;
  protected String country;
  ....
}

public class AddressValidationRequest {
  private AddressRecord addresses[];
  protected ArrayList      actions;
  protected ArrayList      columns;
  protected Properties     options;
  ...
}
```

Should I keep AddressRecord completely hidden inside Request (is it Aggregation?) or expose and access the AddressRecord from outside (Composition)?

(To me, even inheritance seemed like an option to extend AddressRecord to a Request, though I feel they are distinct entities in real world, so I dropped that idea).

What I mean is, should I have AddressRecord as a private object inside Request and add getters/setters in the Request itself for each field in AddressRecord?

Or just add getter/setter to get/set AddressRecord[] from the Request and then set it up outside, say in a controller code?

(This later idea I got when I tried to extract the AddressRecord class from Request in Eclipse like below:

```
public class AddressSearchRequest {

    AddressRecord address;

    public AddressSearchRequest(String format, String customerId, String addressLine1, String suite,
      String city, String state, String postalCode) {
        this.format = format;
        this.customerId = customerId;
        this.address.setAddressLine1(addressLine1);
        this.address.setAddressLine2(Suite);
        this.address.setCity(city);
        this.address.setState(state);
        this.address.setPostalCode(postalcode);
    }

    public void setAddressLine1(String addressLine1) {
        this.address.setAddressLine1(addressLine1);
    }
    public String getSuite() {
        return address.getAddressLine2();
    }
    public void setSuite(String suite) {
        this.address.setAddressLine2(suite);
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return address.getCity();
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.address.setCity(city);
    }
    public String getState() {
        return address.getState();
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.address.setState(state);
    }
    public String getPostalCode() {
        return address.getPostalCode();
    }
    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.address.setPostalCode(postalCode);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

There are actually 2 different types of Requests I am dealing with - a Search Request - takes only one address and may return multiple matches.

A Validation Request may take one or more addresses.

I had them both as Request causing some confusion. corrected it.

**Note:** I am using AddressRecord also in other types of Request(s) and Response classes.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between aggregation and composition is ownership. Composition is stronger. If `Request` is composed of `AddressRecord`s, then `AddressRecord` cannot exist outside of a `Request`. If `Request` aggregates `AddressRecord`s, then you can create `AddressRecord` without the existence of a `Request`.

I don't have a full understanding of your system, but it seems like an `AddressRecord` can exist outside of your `Request`. This would mean that the approach where you provide an accessor and mutator for your collection of `AddressRecord`s. This could take many forms: you can provide a get/set by index, a get/set for the entire collection (in this case, the array), add/remove methods, and so on. Either way, I would recommend that you create `AddressRecord`s outside of `Request` and use them (along with other data) to populate the `Request`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain in detail. I had the AddressRecord outside before, as this is typically the design I see; until I tried to extract some fields and Eclipse did Aggregation. FYI- I am working on a Web Service client to call a 3rd party web service to get our addresses validated and Geocoded. Our main application is in n-tier PowerBuilder running inside old Sybase EAServer. I have to use Java mostly for low level tasks to handle multi-tasking, multi-threads.

Comment: @SamV What do you mean by "Eclipse did Aggregation"? You want aggregation, which is what I described. But I'm not sure how Eclipse does it.

Comment: I got your answer fine. But, I originally had all the fields in the request. Then I try to get "smart" with OO, started pulling out classes. At some point, I selected a bunch of fields inside the class, chose to Refactor -> Extract Class, intending a fully independent class. But, instead that created a new subclass outside (I guess Aggregated) with all the getter/setters for the subclass fields.

Comment: @SamV Yes, there are configuration options and a few different ways. It sounds like you're new to Java - that was Eclipse doing what you told it to do, not necessarily suggesting the appropriate extraction. There should be a way to extract and move methods to other classes in different ways. I'd have to open Eclipse, though, and poke around.

Comment: thanks. Let me just, I finally got a chance to get back into Java after years. Catching up with many new tools, features, concepts. Still manage to get the tasks done so far. I am trying to get it done the right way this time :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two different cases: either your `Request` contains one `AddressRecord`, or it contains multiple ones.  (The question is a bit confusing in this regard.)

If your `Request` is to contain multiple `AddressRecord`s, then the answer is clearly that it has to expose methods to obtain `AddressRecord`s by index or by some other key, so that the caller obtains an `AddressRecord` and works with it.  The `Request` might then also offer methods to add or delete `AddressRecord`s, and specifically the `add()` method might either accept an existing `AddressRecord` to add to the `Request`, in which case the `Request` does not own the `AddressRecords` that it contains, so you have aggregation, or it might create an `AddressRecord` internally, in which case it owns its contents.  The choice is yours.

If your `Request` is to contain a single `AddressRecord`, the same principles apply, you can think of it as being a collection of one item, so there is no need to add or delete items, and the accessor does not need an index or a key. But if I were in your shoes I would definitely use an accessor, so the caller would have to invoke the accessor to obtain a reference to the one and only `AddressRecord` object contained within `Rquest`, and then the caller would have to invoke the `AddressRecord` object directly.

Adding mutator methods to `Request` which delegate to a contained `AddressRecord` is a lot of unnecessary work, it makes your classes hard to maintain, and it gives the false appearance that `Request` is derived from `AddressRecord`, since it exposes a superset of its methods, but without actually having inheritance, since you cannot pass a `Request` there where an `AddressRecord` is expected.

Note: another strategy commonly followed in more modern versions of java and in languages with more complete and more flexible collection models (like C#) would have `Request` expose an actual `List<AddressRecord> getAddressRecords()`, but with java 1.4 I would not try such a thing, due to the lack of type safety.

Comment: I don't agree that if `Request` contains multiple `AddressRecord`s, you need to get/set them by index or key. Why can't you have a `void setAddressRecords(AddressRecord[])` and `AddressRecord[] getAddressRecords()` methods? You can replace the array with the appropriate collection (or, preferably, collection interface). Not that I'm advocating that approach, it could always be useful to have a batch operation to set/get all records at once if they are a collection.

Comment: @ThomasOwens well, one does not preclude the other.  Anyway, you wrote your comment as I was amending my answer to address exactly that.

Comment: Indeed. I think your edits addressed my concerns.

Comment: I do have void setAddressRecords(AddressRecord[]) and AddressRecord[] getAddressRecords(). The Request allows multiple addresses, but most of the time, I will be sending in 1 address record. So, is it proper to also to have setAddressRecord(AddressRecord) and getAddressRecord() to get/set 1 record and internally set it to AddressRecord[1] as special cases?

Comment: @Mike, Thanks for the edits - helps a lot. I agree my original post is a bit confusing. I do have multiple addresses inside. Like I mentioned, as a special case, I deal with mostly one address. I was going back and forth. That's the reason for the 2nd part of the code (I copied it from a different pass of editing in Eclipse). I will try to correct it.

Comment: A pair of `setAddressRecord() and getAddressRecord()` is of course an option, but it has the disadvantage of making ownership of the record unclear: when you invoke `set`, does `Request` just store the reference you gave it, or does it realize a copy of the record?  When you modify the record you obtained by invoking `get`, are you modifying the record contained within the request, or are you only modifying a local copy which you will then have to `set`?  If `AddressRecord` was immutable, this question would be settled, but since it is not, the question is open.

Comment: If you only have a `getAddressRecord()` you might initially confuse someone who might expect there to be a corresponding `set` but will not find any; however, once they get the hang of it, I believe there are fewer things that are unclear or that can go wrong with this approach.

Comment: @Mike I've updated the question - there are actually more than one type of Request - I just called them both Request in my original post causing confusion. As for the Validation Request that takes the multiple Address Records, the Request class won't change the address at all. Controller sets up a request and the address record inside it. Fire a webservice request (after I convert request to XML) and returns XML response. I guess I can always to AddressRecord[1] outside before setting it in (validation) Request. Thanks again for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers go into some good details about different approaches to relating the classes to one another, which is central to what the question asked.  But I would just reinforce the notion that the ultimate best choice of design approaches can and will naturally flow from an *understanding of what the application does and what data is in it*.

For example, are the Request records simply "log entries" whenever a request is made?  Or are they API "messages" that need to be tracked and resolved?  And what about the Validation Requests?  And so on.

The most important advantage of object-oriented design isn't any programming power or functionality it might provide to reuse code.  OOP's great advantage is that it helps *conceptually clarify* the code (with fewer comments) for developers who read it.  If an OO design devolves into a muddle of obtuse relationships (which it quickly can)...then it has defeated its main purpose.